# QGIS 2.8 starts with an error and I am not able to run Python console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, installation, red-hat

I have installed QGIS 2.8 - Wien on Linux Red Hat 7. Unfortunately when I start the application I got this python error:

```
{Couldn't load plugin 'processing' from ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/qgisosr/.qgis2/python', '/home/qgisosr/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/qgisosr/.qgis2//python', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 196, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 28, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 44, in 
    from processing.gui.Postprocessing import handleAlgorithmResults
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/Postprocessing.py", line 36, in 
    from processing.gui.ResultsDialog import ResultsDialog
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/ResultsDialog.py", line 33, in 
    from processing.ui.ui_DlgResults import Ui_DlgResults
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/ui/ui_DlgResults.py", line 61, in 
    from QtWebKit.QWebView import QWebView
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit.QWebView
```

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, Feb 11 2014, 07:46:25) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-13)]

QGIS version:
2.8.1-Wien Wien, exported

Python path: ['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/qgisosr/.qgis2/python', u'/home/qgisosr/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', u'/home/qgisosr/.qgis2//python', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools']}

I his close and QGIS stars.
If I try to launch Python console I get this error:

{Failed to open Python console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/console/__init__.py", line 26, in 
    from console import show_console
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/console/console.py", line 29, in 
    from console_settings import optionsDialog
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/console/console_settings.py", line 24, in 
    from console_compile_apis import PrepareAPIDialog
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/console/console_compile_apis.py", line 28, in 
    from ui_console_compile_apis import Ui_APIsDialogPythonConsole
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/console/ui_console_compile_apis.py", line 70, in 
    from Qsci.qsciscintilla import QsciScintilla
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named Qsci.qsciscintilla
```

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, Feb 11 2014, 07:46:25) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-13)]

QGIS version:
2.8.1-Wien 'Wien', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/qgisosr/.qgis2/python', u'/home/qgisosr/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', u'/home/qgisosr/.qgis2//python', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools']}

Anybody had this issue?

Comment: The first error states that QtWebKit.QWebView is missing. Try to install the QtWebKit package (or QWebView). The second error is similiar, Qsci.qsciscintilla is missing.

Comment: Is your Red Hat version Enterprise (RHEL)?

Comment: If your answer is yes, you can see in this link: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#rhel-centos-scientific-linux that "Python support is strongly limited due to old dependencies. Note: It requires, that ELGIS and EPEL are also installed.".

Comment: Hi Luca, I have installed qtwebkit and yum search qtwebkit
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
============================ N/S matched: qtwebkit =============================
qtwebkit-devel.x86_64 : Development files for qtwebkit
qtwebkit.x86_64 : Qt WebKit bindings

Comment: ANswer for xunlink. Yes I did all installations. I still get the error.

Answer (score 4):

A alternative quick fix (without having to edit the QGIS source) may be to just add dummy modules somewhere on the QGIS python path, e.g.

```
mkdir QtWebKit Qsci
touch QtWebKit/__init__.py Qsci/__init__.py
echo "from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView" > QtWebKit/QWebView.py
echo "from PyQt4.Qsci import QsciScintilla" > Qsci/qsciscintilla.py
```

The python path is given when QGIS shows the error. For example:

```
~/.qgis2/python  # specific to individual user(s)
```

or

```
/usr/share/qgis/python  # requires sudo to edit
```

Comment: On Centos 7.2, I had to install `PyQt4-webkit.x86_64`. Thanks @isedwards

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution of the issue.
I checked **ui_DlgResults.py** file from **/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/ui/** and I have found that QWebView is not imported correctly.
In the file was: **from QtWebKit.QWebView import QWebView**
I have replace with **from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView** and recompile the script using py_compiler. The error is gone.
In addition there are other 3 python scripts with the same error:
**- ui_DlgGetScriptsAndModels.py
- ui_DlgHelpEdition.py
- ui_DlgAlgorithmBase.py**
I have changed all files and recompile them using py_compiler.

For the second error when I tried to start the Python script the error was in the file **ui_console_compile_apis.py** from **/usr/share/qgis/python/console/**.
I have replaced from **Qsci.qsciscintilla import QsciScintilla** with **from PyQt4.Qsci import QsciScintilla**.
Now QGIS works.
I have also notified QGIS project about the changes on their code. Unfortunately I did not get any answer from them.

Comment: I have the same issue on CentOS7. Which is the URL to your bug report? thanks

Comment: I do not get your question. I have reported the bug to qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org. I do not know what was their resolution.

Comment: I see - did anyone respond? The other option is to report at the bugtracker of QGIS: https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis